# fetching multiple rows with new mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, mysqli

I'm using php to connect to mysql database and am using the following function to retrieve multiple rows from database and then add them to an array and send them back. I'm getting internal server error or 500x error messages. I'm not sure what is wrong with this code. I've tried to figure it out but can't get it.

```
public function getUnreadMessages($uname){
          $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT msgid, title, fromuname FROM messages WHERE touname = ? and status = ?");
          $status = 'unread';
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $uname, $status);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3);
                $stmt->store_result();
                $resp = array();
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                        $row = array();
                        array_push($row, $col1, $col2, $col3);
                        array_push($resp, $row);            
            }
            $msg = array('msgid' => $msgid,'title' => $title,'fromuname' => $fromuname);
            $stmt->close();
            return $msg;

        } else {
                        $stmt->close();
                     return NULL;
        }
    }
```

how should I go about doing this? The function that handles the returned results are as follows

```
$app->get('/inbox', 'authenticate', function() use ($app){
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
        global $global_user_name;
        $db = new DbHandler();
        $resp = $db->getUnreadMessages($global_user_name);
        $msgs = array();
        $msgs['status'] = 'success';
        $msgs['version'] = 0.1;
        array_push($msgs, $resp);

        $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode($msgs);
        exit;

});
```

Comment: That is something related to server side, it has not even reach the code end....Check out whether you are using the actual url or not?

Comment: I'm using chrome developer tool to monitor the request and the response headers. The request is being sent and received by the server. The Server closes the connection with a 500 messages. I've faced this issue several times if there are errors on the site. As for error logging, I do have debug enabled. Sometimes, some parse error or trivial errors show up. Other times they dont

Comment: Does server support login via URL? i mean credentials to be passed via url?

Comment: Hi, the problem has been fixed. Please see the answer I wrote below with the corrected function. Basically, I was creating array within the loop. It should be outside

Answer (score 0):

The PDO method automating this is $stmt->fetchAll() :D

```
public function getUnreadMessages($uname)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT msgid,title,fromuname FROM messages WHERE touname = ? and status = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$uname, 'unread']))
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Return `false` if nothing has been found or something like :

```
$msg = [
    [
        'msgid' => 2746,
        'title' => 'Random title',
        'fromuname' => 'SomeGuy'
    ],
    [
        'msgid' => 754,
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'fromuname' => 'Random Name'
    ],
    [
        'msgid' => 27686,
        'title' => 'Unreadable title',
        'fromuname' => 'Training dummies'
    ],
];
```

Comment: I'm still getting errors. I've posted the code that works with this function

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my question. It was that I was creating an array within a loop. This seems to be disallowed. Here's the code that did work in the end

```
public function getUnreadMessages($uname){

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT msgid, title, fromuname FROM messages WHERE touname = ? and status = ?");
                $status = 'unread';
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $uname, $status);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $outer = array();
            $inner = array();
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                    array_push($inner, $col1, $col2, $col3);
            }
            array_push($outer, $inner);
            return $outer;
            $stmt->close();
    }
```